# Ring, but not a field.

Tags: module-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a ring, $F$ a field, and $\phi:R\rightarrow F$ a ring homomorphism. Suppose that exists a bijection $f:R\rightarrow F$ such that $$f(rx+sy) = \phi(r)f(x)+\phi(s)f(y)$$ for all $r,s,x,y\in R$. I think that this does not imply that $R$ is a field, but I am failing to find a (counter) example. Any ideas?

To simplify things, think of $F$ as field containing $R$, or $R$ being a subring of $F$.

Comment: How is the morphism defined? Given two $R$-modules I know the definition of a module morphism, but what is a morphism between an $R$-module and a $F$-module?

Comment: What are $_RR$ and $_FF$? Probably everyone but me knows, sorry. In any case, presumably the first is an $R$-module and the second is an $F$-module - if so, what does it mean to say an $R$-module is isomorphic to an $F$-module?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Nope, I'm having the same issue!

Comment: @Mathematician42 Heh. You must know what the notation $_RR$ means - that's what I was claiming to be uniquely ignorant about.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That is indeed standard notation for $R$ as a left $R$-module.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: You have $f(r)=\phi(r)f(1)$ for all $r$ in $R$ and $f(0)=0$. As $f$ is bijective, we must have $f(1)\neq 0$, for otherwise $f$ would be constant, and then we see that $\phi$ is bijective.

Comment: So, does this mean that $R$ is necessarily a field?

Comment: Yes it does. If a ring is isomorphic to a field (as rings), then the ring is a field.